# Is there a delay in DynamoDB console to show the table's latest contents?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am deleting an item from a DynamoDB table using SDK, but if I check the console, sometimes it remains there even after clicking the refresh button.
Is there a delay in DynamoDB console to show the table's latest contents? I need to make sure whether my code has some issues or the console has some delay. Because, it is quite confusing, in some cases, the item gets disappeared, and in some cases not.

Comment: You can verify the delete operation by adding `ReturnValues: ALL_OLD` in delete request params. And another thing, DynamobDB web console cache the view so perform `scan/query` to check updated results.

Comment: DynamoDB uses eventual consistency for reads by default. Your console will use eventual consistent reads as well, that is why you get out of date reads for the moment. There should be no caching, since the console displays how much RCU was used for the query. I personally never seen this to be 0 which would imply caching.